# dll using a file that is within the dll

Tags: dll

I'm trying to make a dll that a client app can pass an xml string to and then have an xslt file in the dll be used on the xml string, then return the result back to the client.

How do I get the dll to look for the xslt file within itself?  Debugging has shown that the process looks for the xslt file in the folder structure of the test client application I'm using.

I tried making sure the xslt file is identified as an embedded resource of the dll, because I saw to do that in a stack overflow post.  Still same problem though.

Comment: Would it be helpful to show you how Haskell extracts resources from a DLL?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a file in the dll'? A big string constant? A resource?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Haskell? I don't see Haskell mentioned by the OP.

Comment: This is not an XSLT question per se. The question is about how to store a string (that contains a program in any language) in a DLL to be used for dynamic execution during run-time. Please, tag accordingly.

Comment: @Dimitre: I don't see *any* language mentioned.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: You are right. He mentions XSLT, but not as a language but as "xslt file" :)

Comment: C#.  And no it isn't really xslt specific.  It is a dll question - my dll is not successfully locating a file.  The file is physically located within the dll project.

Comment: FYI this link was helpful: [Embed and access resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) -- calling GetManifestResourceStream on the assembly you get from Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

Comment: And this one seems to have gotten me where I need to be: [xslt from assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399419.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming C or C++, you'd typically put the XSLT stylesheet text into a string resource via your resource file, then fish it out into memory, and simply pass it as a string into the relevant COM object to perform the XSLT processing.

Answer (score 0):

You could call GetModuleFileName on yourself to get your file name, open yourself, seek to the appropriate byte (takes some arranging e.g. parse PE for resources), load the bytes into RAM, and pass the resulting byte array into the XSLT handler.

There's got to be a better way but this will work.